# Creating a GameObject or Component based off of an instanced Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using factories to generate Objects, however I am having trouble figuring out how to add these created object instances to the unity scene.
If I add a component of the type, it's a new instance and doesn't have the created data.
If I try and instantiate, It won't work because it's a custom class and has no gameObject.

Is there a common way to do this? or do I have to redesign how this is working?

So far the only thing I can think of is creating an Initialize method in the objects that sets all the properties, and then after the object is created and generated, I create a new Component, and call the initialize method on the GetComponent that I just added, setting the values to the values from the generated object.
Seems like a headache and bad way to do it though.

Basically I'm generating Items, using some Randomization functions to get their rarity/itemType etc, and then creating said Item using factories as I won't know what type they are until the game is already running.
I'm, in theory, trying to generate everything without any need for a database, except a sprite > object connection. But, the more and more I get into this the more I think i'm going to have to have some sort of database.

Long story short, I need the instances in the Unity scene so that when a player clicks on them he can "equip them, disenchant them, etc"

Comment: Look [here](http://answers.unity.com/answers/603984/view.html). You would add a new instance and than you can use reflection to copy all properties to the new instance. @AliKanat [factory pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: Thank you @derHugo